# Is there a director's cut of Jackie Brown?

Tags: alternate-version, jackie-brown

I re-watched Jackie Brown for the first time in a long time on Netflix last night. I know that Netflix usually only shows the theatrical versions of movies, not the director's cuts.

However, from my recollection there was a few scenes missing from Jackie Brown. One in particular that showed the carpark scene where Melanie meets her end from an alternate point of view (such as was done inside the department store when the money exchange takes place - you see it from three distinct points of view).

Did I see a different version of the film (such as a director's cut), or is my memory just playing tricks on me?

Comment: Just for the record, Quentin Tarantino released his director's cut. I guess you meant an "alternate cut"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not a definite answer, but I could find no indication that there ever was a director's cut of Jackie Brown (or any other version that differs from the theatrical one).

However, there are a few deleted scenes that are included on Bluray and DVD:

> - Extended scene with Jackie/Sheronda in the mall's food court.
> - Extended scene with Jackie and Ray in the diner.
> - A scene where Louis and Ordell walk into the Cockatoo.
> - A scene where Jackie is discussing with Max how to set up Ordell.
> - An alternate "for your eyes only" scene.
> - Alternate opening credits sequence.

*Source: [IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0119396/alternateversions)*

Comment: No mention of it on the Wiki page either.  There's a 2-DVD version but it mostly contains what you've mentioned above, along with some documentary/Making Of featurettes.

Comment: Good enough for me. I would have hired it in DVD so it's possible what I am remembering was a featurette or something.